# Como fazer um each dentro de um append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

Estou tentando criar um plugin Jquery porém não consigo adaptar um .each dentro de um .append, como posso utilizá-lo para que funcione dentro do .append?

Segue o meu exemplo abaixo:

```js
var selectBox = $('.select__atual');
var selectOption = $('.select__opcoes__label');

selectBox.click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
  $('.select__opcoes').toggle();
});

selectOption.click(function(){
  var selectName = $(this).text();
  $('.select__atual__text').text(selectName);
});


jQuery.fn.customSelect = function(options){
  
        var settings = $.extend({
            border       : '1px solid red',
            list         : ['Option 1', 'Option 2'],
            defaultText  : 'Choose an option'
        }, options);
  
   return this.each(function(){
     console.log(settings.list);
       $(this)
         .append(`<div class="wrapper-select">
                  <div class="select__atual">
                  <span class="select__atual__text">${settings.defaultText}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="select__opcoes">${settings.list}</div>
                  </div>`)
         .css('border', settings.border);
    });
}
 
$('#mySelect').customSelect({
  border: '1px solid #cecece',
  defaultText: 'Escolha uma opção',
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
main{
  width:600px;
  display:flex;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.wrapper-select{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}
.wrapper-select input{
  display:none;
}
.select__atual{
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  cursor:pointer;
  border:1px solid;
  border-color: #cecece;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  padding:0 15px;
}
.select__atual.open{
  border-bottom:none;
}
.select__opcoes{
  width:100%;
  display:none;
  border:1px solid;
  border-top:none;
  border-color:#cecece;
}
.select__opcoes__label{
  display:flex;
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  align-items:center;
  padding:0 15px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div id="mySelect"></div>
  </main>
```

Comment: vc tem que colocar os argumentos na sua função callback, `this.each(function(idx, element){ ... })` e aí usar esse element dentro do `each`.

Comment: @guijob eu tentei fazer isso mas parece que ele não reconhece os argumentos de dentro dos settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, primeiro temos que corrigir alguns erros. As variáveis declaradas logo no inicio não tem efeito algum, então tomei a liberdade de remove-las. Os eventos `click` movi para dentro do plugin.

Dentro do Template Literals fazemos o `map` do array:

```
${settings.list.map(item => `<div class="select__opcoes">${item}</div>`).join('')}
```

Algumas alterações feitas no *CSS* foi apenas para melhorar a experiência no *SO*.

#### Resultado final

```js
jQuery.fn.customSelect = function(options){
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $('.select__opcoes').toggle();
    });

    $(this).on('click', '.select__opcoes', function() {
        var selectName = $(this).text();
        $('.select__atual__text').text(selectName);
    });

    var settings = $.extend({
        border       : '1px solid red',
        list         : ["Option 1","Option 2"],
        defaultText  : 'Choose an option'
    }, options);

    $(this)
        .append(`<div class="wrapper-select">
            <div class="select__atual">
                <span class="select__atual__text">${settings.defaultText}</span>
            </div>
            ${settings.list.map(item => `<div class="select__opcoes">${item}</div>`).join('')}
        </div>`)
        .css('border', settings.border);
}

$('#mySelect').customSelect({
    border: '1px solid #cecece',
    defaultText: 'Escolha uma opção',
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#mySelect {
  width: 100%;
}
main{
  width: 90%;
  display:flex;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.wrapper-select{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}
.wrapper-select input{
  display:none;
}
.select__atual{
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  cursor:pointer;
  border:1px solid;
  border-color: #cecece;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  padding:0 15px;
}
.select__atual.open{
  border-bottom:none;
}
.select__opcoes {
cursor: pointer;
  width:100%;
  display:none;
  border:1px solid;
  border-top:none;
  border-color:#cecece;
  padding: 14px;
}
.select__opcoes:hover {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}
.select__opcoes__label{
  display:flex;
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  align-items:center;
  padding:0 15px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div id="mySelect"></div>
</main>
```

#### Referência

- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)